# Select One row each from one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following structure for my account management software

```
Transaction
==================
Id | Description | CreditAccountId (FK_AccountId) | DebitAccountId (FK_AccountId)
1  | Tran1       | 1                              | 2  

Account
==================
Id | Title    | Description 
1  | DebitAc  | Debit Account
2  | CreditAc | Credit Account

Posting
==================
Id | Amount  | Currency | TransactionId (FK_Transaction) | TransactionType (Debit/Credit)
1  | 10.00   | EUR      | 1                              | Debit
2  | 10.00   | EUR      | 1                              | Credit
```

Each transaction has 2 postings, one each for debit and credit.

On applying the following query, I am getting each transaction twice.

```
select t.id from [transaction] t 
    JOIN Account da ON t.DebitAccountId = da.Id
    JOIN Account ca ON t.CreditAccountId = ca.Id
    JOIN posting p on p.TransactionId = t.Id 
order by t.id
```

like so

```
TransactionId | Description
1             | Tran1
1             | Tran1
```

this is because the transaction table is joined to posting and two postings are returned, thereby duplicating the transactions.

How can I modify this query so that only one row is returned per transaction ?

Comment: sample data and expected result will help us to understand your requirement

Comment: If there is always a credit and a debit and you only need one, why not just add a `WHERE TransactionType = 'Credit'` or `'Debit'` depending on what you need?

Comment: you can use:  select distinct t.id from [transaction] t.......

Comment: Why do you need to join to Posting at all? You don't refer to any columns in your query. Perhaps all you really need is an EXISTS in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I will also note that, in most general accounting systems, a single transaction can debit or credit more than two accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Rahul mentioned in his comment oyu can use DISTINCT:

```
select distinct t.id
       , t.Description 
from [Transaction_t] t 
    JOIN Account da ON t.DebitAccountId = da.Id
    JOIN Account ca ON t.CreditAccountId = ca.Id
    JOIN posting p on p.TransactionId = t.Id 
order by t.id
```

Here is the demo where you can see the query in action. I have changed the name of your table "Transaction" to "Transaction_t" in my demo.

> > > [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=30f28ea28250511ba8f926a4fab6cf3c)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.id ,
       cp.Amount AS Credit,
       dp.Amount AS Debit,
       cp.Amount - dp.Amount AS Remain
FROM [transaction] t 
    JOIN Account da ON t.DebitAccountId = da.Id
    JOIN Account ca ON t.CreditAccountId = ca.Id
    JOIN posting cp ON p.TransactionId = t.Id AND cp.TransactionType = 'Credit'
    JOIN posting dp ON p.TransactionId = t.Id AND dp.TransactionType = 'Debit'
ORDER BY t.id
```